# How to validate user input on dropdown with next button only if option selected?

Tags: jquery, validation, dropdown

This is my html :

```
<form class="form-inline"> 
<label class="my-1 mr-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelectPref"></label> 
<select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" 
id="inlineFormCustomSelectPref"> 
<option selected>Choose...</option> 
<option value="1">Cleaner</option> 
<option value="2">Handyman</option> 
<option value="3">Landscaping</option>
<option value="4">Audio/VideoSetup</option>
<option value="5">Other</option>
</select> 

</form>

<p2>
<button type="button" 
onClick="location.href='where.html'" 
class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Next</button>
</p2>
```

This is what i started with in js:

```
function howform(){
    var a = ("option.value 1");
    var b = ("option.value 2");
    var c = ("option.value 3");
    var d = ("option.value 4");
    var e = ("option.value 5");

if ($("inlineFormCustomSelectPref").val()= a){
   alert ("please click next");
}}
```

Because i couldn't even get the alert box to work i knew something was wrong. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: How do you call howForm() ?

Comment: if ($("inlineFormCustomSelectPref").val()= a) is an assignment and is always true. It must be if ($("#inlineFormCustomSelectPref").val() == a). You have some errors in your code, i'll suggest you to check it

Comment: inlineform.... is the default id of the bootstrap form code i copied from the bootstrap site.

Comment: I see nothing here about the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited tags.

Comment: When using jQuery inline event attributes are completely obsolete.  Remove `onClick` and replace with a jQuery event handler function.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give two solutions because I have doubt how you are calling that **howform()**

**Solution 1:**
If your calling howform any other ways because i cant see that function call
and your are missing **#** symbol it should be `$("#inlineFormCustomSelectPref").val()`

**Solution 2:**
Just change your code to like this

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#inlineFormCustomSelectPref').change(function(){
         if($(this).val()==1)
         {
             alert('please click next')
         }
     })
 })
</script>
```